# Parsing messages sent with Rocket Chat

Tags: chat, rocket

I am trying to develop an application which parses the text entered in the rocketChat box. I have checked the RocketChat Api: https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/ and there is not any way to catch this event (message sent in box). The only way to do it is to obtain all the messages sent with the method channels.history. https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout rocket chat [node js sdk](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.js.SDK). Use `driver.reactToMessages` function to listen to any messages in a channel